# Can't get Typescript to understand the css prop (emotion) on Material-UI components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, emotion

I'm wanting to setup a Typescript project that is using Material-UI v4.11.4 to use emotion for styling in preparation for the MUI v5 release. The goal is to introduce emotion into the project so that developers can start using the new styling instead of continuing to write styles via the soon to be deprecated `makeStyles` function.

I have everything working except for the fact that I get a type error from Typescript on the `css` prop. I've been searching the documentation for an answer, but can't seem to find anything. Is there some additional types package I need to install in order for Typescript to understand the `css` prop exists on the MUI components?

```js
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

const Btn = () => {
  return (
    // this successfully applies styles, but causes a TS error
    <Button css={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      Click Me
    </Button>
  );
}
```

TS Error:

Property 'css' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I feel stupid. I was thinking it was an issue with MUI not exporting types correctly, but it turns out I just needed to set the `jsxImportSource` in my tsconfig.json

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
}
```

Comment: Sometimes after adding the above you may need to completely close and re-open vscode before the IDE acknowledges the change and plays nicely.

Can be a considerable amount of lost time to the unsuspecting reader before they hit on that themselves... not that I'd be speaking from experience or anything...